# How to assign a returned value from the defer method in python/twisted

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I have a class, which is annotated as @defer.inlineCallbacks
(I want to return the machine list from this)

```
 @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def getMachines(self):
        serverip = 'xx'
        basedn = 'xx'
        binddn = 'xx'
        bindpw = 'xx'
        query = '(&(cn=xx*)(objectClass=computer))'
        c = ldapconnector.LDAPClientCreator(reactor, ldapclient.LDAPClient)
        overrides = {basedn: (serverip, 389)}
        client = yield c.connect(basedn, overrides=overrides)
        yield client.bind(binddn, bindpw)
        o = ldapsyntax.LDAPEntry(client, basedn)
        results = yield o.search(filterText=query)
        for entry in results:
            for i in entry.get('name'):
                self.machineList.append(i)

        yield self.machineList
        return
```

I have another class defined in another python file, where i wnat to call above method and read the machineList.

```
returned =  LdapClass().getMachines()   
  print returned
```

The print says `<Deferred at 0x10f982908>`. How can I read the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inlineCallbacks` is just an alternate API for working with `Deferred`.

You've mostly successfully used `inlineCallbacks` to avoid having to write callback functions.  You forgot to use `returnValue` though.  Replace:

```
yield self.machineList
```

with

```
defer.returnValue(self.machineList)
```

This does not fix the problem you're asking about, though.  `inlineCallbacks` gives you a different API *inside* the function it decorates - but not outside.  As you've noticed, if you call a function decorated with it, you get a `Deferred`.

Add a callback (and an errback, eventually) to the `Deferred`:

```
returned = LdapClass().getMachines()
def report_result(result):
    print "The result was", result
returned.addCallback(report_result)
returned.addErrback(log.err)
```

Or use `inlineCallbacks` some more:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def foo():
    try:
        returned = yield LdapClass().getMachines()
        print "The result was", returned
    except:
        log.err()
```