# yield returns None in python?

Tags: python, twisted

I have 2 python classes in two files.

- file: LdapConnection, class: LdapClass(), method : getMachines(self)

  ```
  @defer.inlineCallbacks
  def getMachines(self):
      c = ldapconnector.LDAPClientCreator(reactor, ldapclient.LDAPClient)
      overrides = {self.basedn: (self.serverip, 389)}
      client = yield c.connect(self.basedn, overrides=overrides)
      yield client.bind(self.binddn, self.bindpw)
      o = ldapsyntax.LDAPEntry(client, self.basedn)
      results = yield o.search(filterText=self.query)
      for entry in results:
          for i in entry.get('name'):
              self.machineList.append(i)

      yield self.machineList
      print self.machineList
      return
  ```

above print statements print all entires in the `machineList`

- file:Twisted, class:Caching, method:loadSettings(self)

  ```
  @defer.inlineCallbacks 
  def loadSettings(self):

      returned =  yield LdapClass().getMachines()  
      print returned
  ```

in the above class my print prints `None`. What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: I have tried to format your code but it is really broken before. So I am not sure am I right. Please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the result of a yield expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695456/what-is-the-result-of-a-yield-expression-in-python)

Comment: Can you reduce your example to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's difficult to get the exact output you see. Your use of yield is curious indeed. The combination of `yield` and `return` looks suspect, as does returning yielded values from functions and yielding lists rather than individual items. I'd expect looped yields or `yield from` although I realise you are using py2 which doesn't have `yield from`.

Comment: The answer to this question is included in on the other similar question you asked about this code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801724/how-to-assign-a-returned-value-from-the-defer-method-in-python-twisted

Answer (score 2):

In `getMachines()`, don't `yield self.machineList`.

In a method decorated by `defer.inlineCallbacks`, what yield does is yield execution until the argument (a `defer.Deferred` object) calls back with a value (if it's not a `defer.Deferred`, it'll simply continue).  (It's similar to the new `await` keyword in Python 3.)  You are using this correctly in `loadSettings()`.

In `getMachines()`, you don't have a `defer.Deferred`; you have a `list`, so it continues.  To return that value to the caller, call `returnValue(self.machineList)` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `loadSettings()` routine is yielding the `getMachines()` generator, not the results from the generator. Perhaps the former should be doing “`yield from`”?

Comment: Given the parens free print, she's using python 2. `yield from` was introduced in 3.3.

Comment: **Time to upgrade!**

Comment: I do agree. Py 2 is dead in the water now (finally)